# Image recognition via webcam - Augmented Reality with Flash

Tags: flash

I have an image
http://img831.imageshack.us/img831/2935/dotn.png
which should be recognized via a webcam. So this image is the original which should be included into the swf. If a person show this image in the webcam, an overlay of a video should added and played (augmented reality).

How can I do this? I found FLARToolkit, but it is not possible because I need a black border which the original image does not has.
Are there other libraries which have this functionality?

Best Regards.

Comment: Can you say a little bit about what the conditions are the user is showing the image to the webcam. Are the lighting conditions always the same, do they always show it from the same distance?

Comment: There are no conditions, because the image is printed on paper and everyone at home should use it with their webcam, so I do not know the resolution, the quality of the webcam, the environmental background, etc.

Comment: goto http://wohzoo.com/app and try cool app with motion tracking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would advice you to look into the FlashSurf kit:

http://blog.inspirit.ru/?p=386

[image]

It's a really amazing library for flash and actionscript. I haven't used this one myself, but other flash libraries from the same developer.

Comment: Yes, I already saw it, but it does not meet my requirements, because first the image has to be tracked at every start of the application. I have to implement a fixed image.

Comment: But can't you implement it so that you save the track data and only loads it later? '

Comment: Or if that isn't possible, "emulates" the tracking on startup from an embedded image?

Answer (score 1):

I found a few resources - haven't tried either. Firstly there is the OpenCV port to AS3 called Marilena [here](http://www.libspark.org/browser/as3/Marilena). The site is in Japanese but if you click on the "English" link you'll find the address to their svn repo, and can check out the source. The project comes with a classifier that will detect certain predefined features in images. What I didn't find was the trainer for the classifier. If you can find how to train the classifier this should work.

That seems a bit of overkill though, since all you need to do is detect a green blob in the image, which is a lot simpler than detecting a face. For that purpose [this blob detection algorithm](http://play.blog2t.net/fast-blob-detection/) should work just fine. You might need to do some tweaking to the code as it is looking for white pixels and you're blob is green. If you're application is being run in a controlled environment (the green is always green) then you shouldn't have too much problems with this. You might also want to make sure that the blob is somewhere in the middle of the image to avoid detecting blobs in the background and so on. Either way a bit of testing with different lighting conditions and different background should give quite nice results.